# How do I provide a transcript of a conversation?

Tags: packages

I'm looking for a package to help with the layout of an interview transcript are there any good packages to do such a task. If possible could you provide a minimum working example?

Perhaps something that aligns the names to the text, and uses a columnar layout for the people vs what they said.

Comment: I will start by https://www.ctan.org/topic/drama-script

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think you really just need the `description` environment, which you can easily tweak to your liking.  What about:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[description]{
  font={\sffamily\bfseries},
  labelsep=0pt,
  labelwidth=\transcriptlen,
  leftmargin=\transcriptlen,
}

\newlength{\transcriptlen}

\NewDocumentCommand {\setspeaker} { mo } {%
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}
  {\expandafter\newcommand\csname#1\endcsname{\item[#1:]}}%
  {\expandafter\newcommand\csname#1\endcsname{\item[#2:]}}%
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}
  {\settowidth{\transcriptlen}{#1}}%
  {\settowidth{\transcriptlen}{#2}}%
}

% Easiest to put the longest name last...
\setspeaker{Bob}
\setspeaker{Billy}[Billy Bob]
\setspeaker{xxx}[Xavier Xanadu III]

% How much of a gap between speakers and text?
\addtolength{\transcriptlen}{1em}%

\begin{document}
\begin{description}

  \Bob I'm looking for a package to help with the layout of an
  interview transcript are there any good packages to do such a
  task. If possible could you provide a minimum working example?

  \Billy I'm looking for a package to help with the layout of an
  interview transcript are there any good packages to do such a
  task. If possible could you provide a minimum working example?

  \xxx Perhaps something that aligns the names to the text, and uses a
  columnar layout for the people vs what they said.

\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image: example-image]

Comment: Hi, great answer! Can I set the speaker from a command like `\newcommand\myself{myname} \setspeaker{\myself}`? I get an error `Missing \endcsname inserted`.

Comment: The `\setspeaker` command is mostly just a way to create commands of the form `\<name>` that expand to `\item[<Name>:]`, so defining a command that would be used in a command-defining command seems odd. Why not simply do `\newcommand\myself{\item[myname:]}`? Or, if you want to have your name string separate: `\newcommand\myself{myname}` and then `\newcommand\me{\item[\myself:]}`; then you can use the command `\myself` elsewhere.

Answer (score 25):

Package `dramatist` is intended to write plays, but I guess an interview is a mini-play too.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{dramatist}
\begin{document}
\begin{drama}
  \Character{John Dow}{dow}
  \Character{Jane Roe}{roe}

  \dowspeaks: I am John Dow.  

  \roespeaks: I am Jane Roe.  \direct{\roe{} leaves}
\end{drama}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Using dramatist on Overleaf, how do I get rid of the following warning: Package dramatist Warning /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/dramatist/dramatist.sty