# Shifted Quote environment

Tags: setspace

By some weird standards I need to create a quote environment following some strict rules. (as we can see in attached figure)

[image]

While the document uses 1.5 spacing the quotation should use regular (1) spacing. Be  2.5cm  shifted to right (the whole paragraph) and use smaller fontsize.

Right now I'm using lualatex and I use `setspace` package to set document line spacing with the command `\onehalfspacing`. I tried many things but was not able to get this working. Hence I came here to ask you how to accomplish that.

Comment: Apart from that, you might want to include a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that includes the documentclass as well as the relevant packages and shows what aou have tried so far.

Comment: I always do this, but in this time I didn't have anything to show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `xparse` to define the new environment.

I also used `biblatex` to get more flexibility in typesetting citations.

```latex
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{oliveira1995,
  author={Oliveira, X.},
  title={whatever},
  year={1995},
}
@article{levi-strauss1970,
  author={Levi-Strauss, A. and Xyz, X. and Abc, Y. and Somebody, S.},
  title={whatever},
  year=1970,
}
@article{laraia2006,
  author={Laraia, L.},
  title={whatever},
  year=2006,
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[margin=2.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{setspace}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\MakeUppercase{#1}}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{squote}{omb}
 {%
  \list{}{
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{2.5cm}%
    \setlength{\rightmargin}{0pt}%
  }%
  \singlespacing\small\item\relax \enquote{#3}
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{%
    \parencite{#2}%
  }{%
    \parencite[#1]{#2}%
  }%
  \endlist
 }{}

\onehalfspacing

\begin{document}

Conforme \textcite[30]{oliveira1995} relativizar é constituinte do próprio 
conhecimento antropológico. Sendo relativizar uma atitude epistêmica,
eminentemente antropológica, em que o pesquisado busca fugir do etnocentrismo. 
\begin{squote}[239]{levi-strauss1970}
A noção de evolução biológica corresponde a uma hipótese dotada de um dos mais altos 
coeficientes de probabilidade gue podem encontrar-se no dominio das ciências naturais; 
ao passo que o conceito de evolução social ou cultural só conduz: no máximo: a um 
procedimento sedutor, mas perigosamente cómodo: de apresentação dos fatos.
\end{squote}

Este trecho de \textcite{levi-strauss1970} nos ajuda compreender o que 
\textcite[93]{laraia2006} diz sobre a lógica de um sistema cultural depende 
da compreensão das categorias constituídas pelo mesmo \parencite[93]{laraia2006}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `authoryear`  bibtex snippet will be very helpful, even not related to the OP. What is the `omb` in the `NewDocumentEnvironment` ?

Comment: Removing `babel` and `fontenc` and replacing for `polyglossia`, is this a `lualatex` compatible code?

Comment: @Lin Sure, why not?

Comment: Tried here and received: `LaTeX error: "xparse/unknown-argument-type"` `Unknown argument type 'b' for the command '\environment squote'.`

Comment: @Lin Update your TeX distribution.

Comment: Using overleaf right now for collaboration with other team members. I will try locally. Thanks

Comment: @Lin Sorry, Overleaf uses TeX Live 2017. It's irremediably lagging behind.

Answer (score 5):

This is very easy with the `quoting` package and its eponymous environment:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %
\usepackage{setspace} %
 \usepackage{quoting} %
\usepackage{lipsum}
\quotingsetup{font={footnotesize, noindent}, leftmargin=2.5cm, rightmargin=0cm}

 \begin{document}

\onehalfspacing

 \lipsum[2]

\begin{singlespacing}
    \begin{quoting}[]
    Sed feugiat. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient
     montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Ut pellentesque augue sed urna.
     Vestibulum diam eros, fringilla et, consectetuer eu, nonummy id,
     sapien. Nullam at lectus. In sagittis ultrices mauris. Curabitur
     malesuada erat sit amet massa. Fusce blandit. Aliquam erat volutpat.
     Aliquam euismod. Aenean vel lectus. Nunc imperdiet justo nec dolor.
    \end{quoting}
\end{singlespacing}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is an adapted version of [one of my previous answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/424047/134144):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\onehalfspacing

\usepackage{changepage}
\newenvironment{myquote}{\par\vspace{\baselineskip}\begin{singlespace*}\begin{adjustwidth}{2.5cm}{0cm}\small}{\end{adjustwidth}\end{singlespace*}\par\vspace{\baselineskip}}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{myquote}
\lipsum[5]
\end{myquote}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: where `changepage` and `etoolbox` are used?

Comment: @Lin: `changepage` in needed for the `adjustwidth` environment that allows to locally change the margins (I used it for the 2.5 cm indentation from the left margin). `etoolbox` is a leftover from my previous answer and is not neede. I have therefore removed it from the MWE.